# jquery context menu on many divs show only on condition

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I use a contextmenu on multiple div containers. Depending on the content of this container I can choose one or more options of the menu. the others are not shown.
For this I use the build option of the menu.

```
    $.contextMenu(
    {
        selector: '[id^=calendarContentFETitle]',
        autoHide: true,
        className: 'calendarContextMenu',
        callback: function (key)
        {
            if(key == "shifts")
            {
                calendarShowShifts();
            }
            if(key == "overtime")
            {
                calendarShowOverTimes();
            }
        },
        build: function($triggerElement)
        {
            var job = getJobFromDiv($triggerElement);
            if(job.isShift)
            {
                return { items: {
                    "shifts": {name: i18next.t('default:calendar.contextmenu.shifts'), icon: "fa-info-circle"} 
            } };
            }
            if(job.isOvertime)
            {
                return { items: {
                    "overtime": {name: i18next.t('default:calendar.contextmenu.overtime'), icon: "fa-info-circle"}
            } };
        }
    });
```

That is working fine, but when the job is no kind of this two types, I got an error in the console, that it returns no items (What is correct, but that is what I want).
How can I not show the context menu if the job is not kind of this two types ?

I know a possible solution is to add and remove the context menu to each div seperatly and change it each time the type of the div changes, but because this are very much divs it will be much overhead in code. So I think one menu for all divs will be much smarter.

As requested an example of one created div

```
    <div id="calendarjob_56463" class="draggable" style="left: 171px; top: 0px; width: 138px; height: 26px; line-height: 26px; background: #f289fa;">
        <div id="calendarJobAlert"></div>
        <div id="calendarJobTitle" style="left: 0px;">
            <div id="title" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 4px; right: 4px; height: 12px; top: 2px; line-height: 12px; white-space: nowrap; ">Urlaub</div>
            <div id="subtitle" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 4px; right: 4px; height: 12px; bottom: 2px;  line-height: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Some HTML would be nice

Comment: All the divs are created dynamically with JS. So there is nothing like a static HTML except the content container which is just a div with an absoslute position in the app.

Comment: There's a lot of guess-work necessary when there's no markup. Why can't you copy and paste the dynamically generated HTML that causes the problem?

Comment: I dont know what you need the html for but I have added an example